# Creating a dropdown select field with 4 predefined options in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to create a dropdown select field in my 'kudos' new form with 4 predefined company values 'Honesty','Ownership', 'Passion' and 'Accountability'. The company_*values*_id are a part of the 'kudos' table. As far I know the `collection select` written as below
  `<%=f.collection_select :company_value_id, CompanyValue.all, :id , :title %>` gives only the option to take the whole table company values into account and not the predefined values, whereas I use the `select_tag` and `options_for_select` written as below
   `<%= select_tag(:company_value_id, options_for_select([['Honesty', 1], ['Ownership',2],['Passion',3],['Accountability',4]])) %>` gives me the
`NoMethodError in KudosController#create undefined method company_value' for #<Kudo id: nil, title: "s", content: "s", giver_id: 1, receiver_id: 2, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, company_value_id: nil>`

I'm rather new to rails so sorry if this issue seems trivial. I wlil also paste here my new.html.erb file `

\

```
<h1\>Create a new Kudo\</h1\>

\<% if @kudo.errors.any?%\>
    \<h2\>The following errors prevented the Kudo from being saved\</h2\>
    \<ul\>
        \<% @kudo.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %\>
            \<li\>\<%= msg %\>\</li\>
        \<% end %\>
    \</ul\>
\<% end %\>
\<%= form_with scope: :kudo, url: kudos_path, local: true do |f| %\>


  \<p\>
    \<%= f.label :title %\>\<br/\>
    \<%= f.text_field :title %\>
  \</p\>
  \<p\>
    \<%= f.label :content %\>\<br/\>
    \<%= f.text_area :content %\>
  \</p\>
  \<p\>
    \<%=f.label :receiver %\>\<br/\>
    \<%=f.collection_select :receiver_id, Employee.all, :id , :email %\>
  \</p\>
  \<p\>
    \<%=f.label :company_value %\>\<br/\>
  \</p\>
  \<p\>
    \<%= f.submit %\>

  \</p\>

\<% end %\>
```

and my kudos controller

```
  def index
    @kudos = Kudo.includes(%i[giver receiver]).all
  end

  def new
    @kudo = Kudo.new
    if current_employee.number_of_available_kudos <= 0
      flash[:alert] = 'You have used all your kudos'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @kudo = Kudo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @kudo = Kudo.new(kudo_params)
    @kudo.giver_id = current_employee.id
    Employee.transaction do
      @kudo.save!
      @current_employee.number_of_available_kudos -= 1
      @current_employee.save!

      flash[:notice] = 'Kudo was created successfully'
      redirect_to root_path
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @kudo = Kudo.find(params[:id])
    if @kudo.update(kudo_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Kudo was edited successfully'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @kudo = Kudo.find(params[:id])
    @kudo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = if @kudo.destroy
                       'Kudo was deleted successfully'
                     else
                       'Kudo delete failed'
                     end
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def kudo_params
    params.require(:kudo).permit(:title, :content, :giver_id, :receiver_id, :company_value_id)
  end
end
```

and my schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2023_02_27_103148) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "admins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admins_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admins_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "company_values", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["title"], name: "index_company_values_on_title", unique: true
  end

  create_table "employees", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "number_of_available_kudos", default: 10, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_employees_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_employees_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "kudos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.text "content", null: false
    t.integer "giver_id", null: false
    t.integer "receiver_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "company_value_id", null: false
    t.index ["company_value_id"], name: "index_kudos_on_company_value_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "kudos", "company_values"
end
```

Comment: Check if property exist on the active record, every use properties on form should be exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `select_tag` does not nest the value properly in the `params`. Just use [`select`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease) which you can call in the form (`f`) object instead:

```
<%= f.select(:company_value_id, 
             [['Honesty', 1], ['Ownership', 2],['Passion', 3], ['Accountability', 4]]) %>
```